# CyberSource payout unsucessfull when we put businessApplicationId = "CP"

Tags: cybersource, payout

We are trying to pay a client's credit card bills, for that we have to choose "businessApplicationId": "CP" in payout api, Am i right?

Request format is :

```
{
  "clientReferenceInformation": {
    "code": "111111113"
  },
  "orderInformation": {
    "amountDetails": {
      "totalAmount": "111.00",
      "currency": "USD"
    }
  },
  "merchantInformation": {
    "merchantDescriptor": {
      "name": "Sending Company Name",
      "locality": "FC",
      "country": "US",
      "administrativeArea": "CA",
      "postalCode": "94440"
    }
  },
  "recipientInformation": {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "address1": "Paseo Padre Boulevard",
    "locality": "Foster City",
    "administrativeArea": "CA",
    "country": "US",
    "postalCode": "94400",
    "phoneNumber": "6504320556"
  },
  "senderInformation": {
    "referenceNumber": "1234567890",
    "account": {
      "fundsSource": "05",
      "number": "1234567890123456789012345678901234"
    },
    "name": "Company Name",
    "address1": "900 Metro Center Blvd.900",
    "locality": "Foster City",
    "administrativeArea": "CA",
    "countryCode": "US"
  },
  "processingInformation": {
    "businessApplicationId": "CP",
    "networkRoutingOrder": "V8",
    "commerceIndicator": "internet"
  },
  "paymentInformation": {
    "customer": {
      "customerId": "C99A860705336053E053AF598E0A0D43"
    }
  }
}
```

we get the following response:

```
{
  "id": "6290386260456808404006",
  "submitTimeUtc": "2021-08-15T14:43:46Z",
  "status": "SERVER_ERROR",
  "reason": "SYSTEM_ERROR",
  "message": "Error - General system failure."
}
```

Our configuration is :

```
Authentication type:  HTTP Signature
Sample Request : Payout(Token)
Payment Processor Type : Chase Paymentech (Default)
Sandbox Credentials :
Merchant ID : Priya1234
```

Previously cybersource team had enabled tokenization and payout in our Merchant Id : Priya1234,
Currently we are in a test environment, Is there anything that we have missed here?
Also Please let us know if there are any other options available to pay client's credit card bills.